# Deploy to OSGi container using bndtools?

Tags: gradle, bundles, bnd, bndtools

I have a multi-bundle project that builds using gradle and bnd plugin. Dependency management is through bnd. I am able to launch and run my bundles in eclipse.

I'm wondering what the proper deployment workflow is through bnd. The `release` task puts all my bundles in a release repository - I just used a filerepo - so I have all my deployable bundles in one folder.

- How do I collect the correct dependencies? Is there a bnd/gradle task?
- Using Jenkins for CI builds, how do I deploy to a remote karaf or virgo container?

Comment: for the first question, `gradle export` and `gradle runbundles` did the job for me